# No first post reviews for 13 hours?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, first-posts

I was reading [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348805/first-posts-reviews-not-working-coming-in-anymore) about a lack of first post reviews on multiple sites. It got my curiosity, so I went to the first post review queue and noticed there had not been a review in the queue for 13 hours.

Reading through [the review history](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/history), this is very strange. There are multiple reviews in this queue every hour and everyone knows this site has a large amount of first timers asking questions.

I just wanted to post this here to get the attention of staff and to show that this seems to be a bug happening here too.

Comment: First posts are back now, can a mod put a staus-completed on this?

Comment: Fixed as per the comment by developer on [Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348824/177471) and confirmed by all of us in here :)